# Robust solution for large dynamically generated downloads in a cloud environment?

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, download, cloud, ibm-cloud

We have issues with the stability of large and slow dynamically generated downloads. I am seeking a best practice solution if it exists.

Users can run database queries and export resulting documents in a ZIP file. Queries can return millions of documents, resulting in large and slow downloads. Sufficiently slow downloads invariably fail.

We have the following components:

- Cloudant databases
- Java EE application (CDI, JAX-RS, WebSocket)
- WebSocket API specifically for downloads
- Bluemix cloud
- Blue/Green deployment via Cloud Foundry CLI
- JavaScript client

In the past we used HTTP for downloads. We tried Response with MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM and StreamingOutput as well from JAX-RS. Unfortunately they suffered from severe problems:

- Memory runs out from buffering file contents before putting them into a Response.
- Bluemix kills application if it takes more than a few minutes to answer with a Response.
- HTTP limitations do not allow exceptions during StreamingOutput. HTTP 200 followed by data is indistinguishable from HTTP 200 followed by partial data and error message.
- Bluemix kills HTTP connections after a few hundred megabytes of traffic.
- Bluemix kills HTTP connections after ~20 minutes.

To circumvent these issues we created a WebSocket based <strike>hack</strike> solution. For every download we generate a unique id, send the data in 1MB chunks, and send exceptions on a side channel. This solution is still not perfect:

- We have to merge chunks in client memory. Firefox does not support Streams API.
- Bluemix still seems to kill the connection after an hour or so.
- Deployments interrupt downloads.
- Connection problems interrupt downloads.

I have a few ideas in mind how to solve these issues:

- Serializable beans that can be transferred across servers. Serialization and version differences complicate this somewhat.
- Central download server that is long-lived. Cloud issues still remain.
- Downloads explicitly provide chunks rather than a stream that is broken into chunks. Needs rework of existing download providers.
- Client creates many requests for chunks instead of relying on an open connection.

However I am not sure how to proceed. I do not have sufficient experience with cloud infrastructures. I am seeking for existing solutions and best practices. Surely this issue must be common that other people have encountered these issues? I would appreciate any help, and thank you in advance!

Comment: To the outside your app or solution looks like it could impact "good neighbors" in a shared infrastructure. What is the largest file you expect to be downloaded? What are the users doing with those files?

Comment: Yes I guessed Bluemix has a strict concept of acceptable HTTP requests and responses, and large dynamically generated downloads do not fit that concept.

Comment: Files are 1-3GB currently, not huge by file sharing standards, but enormous compared to the small request-response concept. The main issue is that downloads are slow, and invariably hit some connection timeout or error. Maybe I should rephrase my post in hindsight.

Comment: Our application is a database archiving solution for obsolete HR systems. It uses Cloudant databases with custom encryption. Users are HR people who have to deal with HR data such as employees and such. Currently the largest database has ~2 million documents.

Comment: There is no Bluemix, but IBM Cloud. One runtime technology is Cloud Foundry with its way of running apps in a shared environment. Why are you zipping the data and not streaming the result set of docs to the client? Are the HR docs JSON or are you misusing Cloudant as Object Storage?

Comment: BTW: This tutorial features a secure file sharing app. Cloudant manages the metadata, Object Storage holds the custom-encrypted real docs https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/cloud-e2e-security.html

Comment: IBM Cloud of course :)

We used StreamingOutput and it made more sense to ZIP data instead of sending one by one. And I am not sure if JavaScript supports ZIP files in a cross browsers way. However I think we should need to move to sending individual documents or chunks in many requests, instead of maintaining a connection.

Comment: We use Cloud Foundry CLI with the liberty-for-java buildpack.

The documents are in JSON with some encrypted fields. We make extensive use of Cloudant features like indices, counts, attachments, etc.

Thank you for the tutorial, I will take a look at it. However we use a custom encryption, I do not expect existing services to support it.